# Understanding arg min with restrictive index

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation

So I have looked through a handful of "What is arg min" questions on here before posting this, but I haven't found anything about using an inequality as an index. Specifically, I would like to know what this means:

$$t=\arg\min_{0\leq x\leq 1}(f(x))$$

What happens if the global minimum of the function lies outside of $(0,1)?$ I have also seen:

$$t=\arg\min_{x\in\Bbb{X}}(f(x))$$

where $\Bbb{X}$ is some set. How would we even evaluate this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty straight forward isn't it?  According to Wikipedia the difference between "min f(x)" and "arg min f(x)" is that "min f(x)" returns the minimum value of f while "arg min f(x)" returns the value of x at which f(x) is min.

For example, if $f(x)= x^2+ 1$ then "min f(x)" is 1 while "arg min f(x)" is 0 because f(0)= 1 while f(x)> 1 for any other value of x.

Now, what about "$arg min_{1\le x\le 2}$"?  The global minimum is not in that set but that is irrelevant!  We are not asking about a global minimum, we are asking about the smallest value for x in that set.  f(1)= 2 and f(x)> 2 for all other x in [1, 2] so $min_{1\le x\le 2} f(x)= 2$ while $arg min_{1\le x\le 2} f(x)= 1$.

Comment: And what about the second part of my question? By the way, I know what arg min means, which is indicated by the sentence "I have looked through a handful of "What is arg min" questions on here before posting this".